# unbounded inverse of injective linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $T$ be an injective linear operator. Let $x\in H$ and $Tx$ can be written as an infinite sum of vectors in $T(H)$, i.e. $Tx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x_{n}$, which $a_{n}$ are some specific complex numbers and $x_{n}$ are some specific vectors in $T(H)$. We apply $T^{-1}$ to $Tx$ and it equals $x$.

If, in the proof of injectivity of $T$, we let $y\in ker(T)$ and express $y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}e_{n}$, which $e_{n}$ are the basis, allowing $b_{n}$ to be any complex numbers, and we conclude that $b_{n}=0$ for all $n$(without using the fact that $x\in H$), without the boundedness of $T^{-1}$, can we conclude that $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}T^{-1}x_{n}$?

What I am thinking is, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}T^{-1}x_{n}$ does not belong to $H$, that it must be certain sum of $e_{n}$(which is not in $H$), contradicting the injectivity of $T$, am I reasoning correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any sort of topology to prove that the injectivity of a linear map only depends on its kernel:

- ($\implies$) If $T$ is injective and $Tx=0$, then $Tx=T0$ so $x=0$ by the definition of injectivity (**note that here we are not applying any sort of inverse**).
- ($\impliedby$) On the other side, if $\ker T= \{0\}$ then $Tx=Ty$ implies that $T(x-y)=0$, so $x-y\in\ker T$ and $x-y=0$.

It is also important to mention that the equation
$$T^{-1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nT^{-1}(x_n)$$
does not hold in general and it is for several reasons:

1. The operator $T^{-1}$ does not have to be defined on every $x_n$. Let for example $T:\ell^2\rightarrow \ell^2$ defined by
   $$T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(0,x_1,x_2\dots)$$
   and consider the basis of $\ell^2$ given by
   $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots),e_2=(1,1,0,\dots),\dots$ and observe that even though $T$ is injective, $T^{-1}$ is not well defined on any $e_j$.
2. $T^{-1}$ might not be continuous. Since any infinite summation is a limit of a sequence and any sequence limit is the limit of a summation, you can prove that being able to pass the operator $T^{-1}$ under the summation symbol implies the continuity of $T^{-1}$.